# How to Delete or deprecate completed Envelope

Tags: docusignapi

I have the following scenario:

- Sender "S" creates an envelope for Recipient1 "R1" and Recipient2 "R2" via the API.
- R1 and R2 sign, and the Envelope "E1" is completed.
- Some conditions change in the system, which causes S to send a new envelope to R1 and R2, which contains updated documents of course.
- R1 and R2 sign, and the second Envelope "E2" is completed.

In this scenario E2 should deprecate or even delete E1. The problem is down the line R2 needs to review all the documents he already signed, and it's confusing having both E1 and E2 in the Completed folder.

As far as I know Voiding a Completed envelope is not possible. Ideally I'd like to find a way for S to move E2 to the recycle bin on R2's account.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the "**Move Envelope**" operation to delete the envelope, as described in on p174 of the REST API guide (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf).  According to the guide's description of the **Move Envelope** operation: `"This can be used to delete envelopes by using “recyclebin” as folderId."`

### **UPDATE (Example)**

**Scenario #1:**

- S1 (sender) sends Envelope to 1 recipient -- R1 (recipient #1).
- S1 and R1 are both members within the SAME DocuSign Account.  (The
  "API user" -- i.e., the user that serves as the "Authenticating" user
  for all API requests -- is also a member of the same Docusign
  Account. If in your scenario the "Sender" is serving as the "Autheticating" user in all API requests, then you wouldn't necessarily need a separate user/membership for an "API User".)
- R1 signs the envelope. (The Envelope is now Complete.)

**Operation A:  API request moves the Sender's copy of the Envelope to his Deleted folder.**

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{acctId}}/folders/recyclebin
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"SendOnBehalfOf":"SenderS1_email@gmail.com","Username":"APIUser_email@outlook.com","Password":"APIUser_Password","IntegratorKey":"IntKey"}
{ 
 "envelopeIds": ["B547562E-5CFC-4989-913E-501CD88F1506"]
}
```

Note that in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of the request:

- The "Authenticating" user's credentials (**Username**, **Password**)
  corresponds to the user that has Account-wide-API-rights within that
  account.
- The value of **SendOnBehalfOf** corresponds to the Sender's membership
  email address within that same DocuSign account, and specifies the
  account to act on.
- If the Sender's credentials are being used as the "Autheticating"
  user in the API request, then you wouldn't need to include the
  **SendOnBehalfOf** property in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header.

**RESULT:** 
When S1 logs into the DocuSign web console, he sees that the Envelope now resides in his "Deleted" folder.

**Operation B:  API request moves the Recipient's copy of the Envelope to her Deleted folder.**

```
PUT https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/{{acctId}}/folders/recyclebin
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"SendOnBehalfOf":"RecipientR1_email@gmail.com","Username":"APIUser_email@outlook.com","Password":"APIUser_Password","IntegratorKey":"IntKey"}
{ 
 "envelopeIds": ["B547562E-5CFC-4989-913E-501CD88F1506"]
}
```

Note that in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header of the request:

- The "Authenticating" user's credentials (**Username**, **Password**) again
  corresponds to the user that has Account-wide-API-rights within that
  account.
- The value of **SendOnBehalfOf** corresponds to the Recipient's membership email address within that same DocuSign account, and specifies the account to act on.

**RESULT:** 
When R1 logs into the DocuSign web console, she sees that the Envelope now resides in her "Deleted" folder.

**NOTE:**  The most critical component of the "Move (Delete) Envelope" operation working as described above is that the "Authenticating" user for each API request (**Username** and **Password** in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header) MUST be a member of the SAME DocuSign Account as the user who's account is being acted upon (i.e., the membership that corresponds to **SendOnBehalfOf** in the **X-DocuSign-Authentication** header).

Comment: Updated answer to include more information, including code examples.

Comment: I successfully able to delete this document via web api. I am getting 200 code as OK status. But I am able to access that document via the link I received before in the mail. Is it NOT completely removed from the DocuSign repository?

Comment: Envelopes in the Deleted Items folder are deleted automatically (by a DocuSign batch process) once daily -- so I'd expect for items you Delete to be available in the interim time between when you move it to Deleted Items folder and when the Deleted Items folder is purged (by DocuSign's batch process). From DocuSign's support forum (http://community.docusign.com/t5/Miscellaneous/Deleting-Envelopes/td-p/25985): "When deleting an envelope...it will be sent to the Deleted Items folder, and will only be accessible until midnight of that day."